# How should a javascript variable in a parent view be changed by the loaded child partial view?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-partialview

This is in asp.net mvc 3, however I think this situation is rather generic.

I have a partial view which is loaded from ajax as a preview. In the preview, there is a checkmark that can be selected if part of the previewed action is incorrect. I need to capture that back in the view which launched the preview. I had set about doing it like this:

```
<script>
 var checkmark = false;
 $.ajax(/*load view*/);
 function calledLaterAfterPartialViewRendered(){
  if( checkmark == true ){
    //action
  }
 }
</script>
```

loaded view:

```
<script>
 //checkmark's state will be determined by the user
 $("#SomeCheckBoxInput").click(function(){ checkmark = this.value; });
</script>
```

Once the state is determined, the entire partial view is removed from the DOM. Is there a better practice for accessing the state? I know that checkmark will be available in the loaded view, and that the function that gets called after the loaded view goes away will be able to access an updated variable. However, it seems that this may not be best for readability.

Is this standard, is there a best practice in this situation?

Comment: So, no, there is no standard for this.

Comment: Too bad this is closed as too localized. I have this question as well. Now its not any more 'too localized' is it?

Comment: On an other note, OP should have opened a bounty on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see what you are asking now. Just check to see if the checkbox is checked in the body of your function. So your checkbox looks like:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='check'/>
```

In your function:

```
if ($('#check').prop('checked')){
    // The checkbox is checked
}
```

Comment: The issue is not getting the variable into the loaded view, it is getting it back into the parent view from the loaded view. Also note, that checkmark's state will be determined by the user.

Comment: Can you please reword your question then? If the checkmark will be clicked by the user, then what does `checkmark = true;` in script tags have to do with anything?

Comment: That will be the end result of a click from the user. I will reword the question, as I thought it was obvious from the explanation.

Comment: Why on earth would you maintain a global variable for a simple state transition?

Comment: @SimpleCoder - Sorry, but I think my brevity lead to a lack of inclusive detail. "In your function", I am assuming you meant in the parent view. However, by the time that function is accessed, the preview is gone, and so is the input. The preview is similar to lightbox.

Comment: @jcolebrand - Not really that simple, just tried to condense it to focus on the heart of the issue. Perhaps this is drilled too far down.

Comment: Must you remove it from the DOM then? Couldn't you attach it elsewhere to requery later? Or maybe stick it in localStorage, etc?

Comment: @TravisJ: Does your lightbox implementation have the option to just hide to dialog, instead of destroying it? You could still read the check off of a hidden checkbox.

Comment: @SimpleCoder - I could do that, but it seems to be in the wrong direction.  In my opinion it is more readable to have the child change, in one small spot, a single variable in the parent, rather than reading from a child's hidden implementation.

Comment: @TravisJ: Don't get hung up on the idea of child and parent views - that doesn't matter. It's better *not* to pollute the global namespace under most circumstances, and this is no exception. That is in fact the 'wrong direction'. This is a better option.

Comment: @SimpleCoder - "Pollute the global namespace" via leaving a whole view in place versus or 1 javascript variable. I disagree. The "idea of child and parent views" was merely a way to explain that there is a view being launched from ajax. They are perhaps more like siblings in that they share the same scope for variables and functions. However, declarations made in the "child" will be removed if the child is removed and that is what makes the distinction. Leaving the entire loaded view when its function is done *is* bad practice.

Comment: @TravisJ: No, there is a *big* difference between the global variable scope (which I'm referring to) and the DOM. You asked for a standard way of doing this, which is what I gave you. It's the same suggestion that jcolebrand gave.